# Example of an Oracle PIVOT clause with subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, subquery, pivot

Oracle's [definition of the PIVOT clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#sthref9288) specifies that there is a possibility to define a subquery in the `IN` clause. A fictional example of what I would imagine this to be is this

```
... PIVOT (AVG(salary) FOR (company) IN (SELECT DISTINCT company FROM companies))
```

With that, however, I get an `ORA-00936: Missing expression` error. Unfortunately, errors from this new `PIVOT` clause are usually rather cryptic. Can anyone give me a good example of how a subquery can be used in the `IN` clause of the `PIVOT` clause?

Comment: Thanks for the discovery. I gave up long before I read even half of that documentation.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Apparently, I was too lazy to read to the end of the documentation... Further down, the documentation states:

> subquery A subquery is used only in conjunction with the XML keyword. When you specify a subquery, all values found by the subquery are used for pivoting. [...]

This will work

```
PIVOT XML (AVG(salary) FOR (company) IN (SELECT DISTINCT company FROM companies))
```

See the full documentation

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE

Comment: So I saw that this returns output in XML format. Any idea how to get normal output(table) as plain PIVOT would give?

Comment: @tumchaaditya: I'm not sure if that's possible. But to be sure, feel free to ask a new Stack Overflow question. And link to it from here, I'm curious, myself...

Comment: I ended up constructing the results of that subquery dynamicaly outside the SQL with pivot. I mean I run the subquery separately and pipe that output to the main query

Answer (score 2):

i had a similar requirement. I achieved this via pl sql wrote a dynamic sql and added it to the pivot IN clause. Ofcourse pivot query was also a dynamic sql. But in normal pivot clause this is not possible, using sql.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include more detail. Simply giving a general outline of your solution is not helpful for future readers.